# CSS Selector for an a list of items with no child lists

Tags: css, css-selectors, hierarchy

**Context**
I have a database of containing functions arranged in a hierarchy.  I have control over all levels of the infrastructure running on a Linux environment.  My intention is to produce a hierarchy display which has the ancestors in a horizontal format and the children in a vertical format.

Based on an understanding that I wish to separate presentation from function I have a database query that produces the HTML below.

**Question**

In English I want to know the how I might specify a css selector to select the unordered lists (ul) that has no unordered lists within its children and display and display the children in a vertical format.

Given the html below this would select both:

- The unordered list belonging to **Parent function 1**
- The unordered list belonging to **Function number 2.3**

**HTML**

```
<body>
<ul>
  <li><div class="function">Parent function 1</div>
    <ul>  <!-- Select this one -->
     <li><div class="function">Function number 1.1</div></li>
     <li><div class="function">Function number 1.2</div></li>
     <li><div class="function">Function number 1.3</div></li>
     <li><div class="function">Function number 1.4</div></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><div class="function">Parent function 2</div>
   <ul>
    <li><div class="function">Function number 2.1</div></li>
    <li><div class="function">Function number 2.2</div></li>
    <li><div class="function">Function number 2.3</div>
     <ul>  <!-- and this one! -->
      <li><div class="function">Sub function number 2.3.1</div></li>
      <li><div class="function">Sub function number 2.3.2</div></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

My thoughts are that it is something like the below which does not work.

**CSS**

```
ul > li:not(> ul)
```

Comment: This isn't possible using CSS. You'll need JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: The question has now been reopened; you may add your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the context that I can directly query the database to produce the html tags the best solution is to modify the database query to explicitly define the parent nodes.  Two benefits are that the CSS can use an explicit selector rather than a javascript work around and secondly the html becomes (IMHO) more readable.

As a additional benefit it is useful to provide additional detail when changing the query giving more flexibility to definition of the output style.

The query will now produce output that explicitly declares the class for the node (ul) in the hierarchy based on the whether the parent node has only children or not.  So a node can be one of two possible classes being leaf or parent.  Parent nodes can then be assigned one of three secondary classes being of_leaves,  of_parents or of_both.  To add further information each div.function can also be classified with parent or leaf.

Thus the output from the database query will produce the following html.

**HTML**

```
<body>
<ul class="parent of_parents">
  <li><div class="function parent">Parent function 1</div>
    <ul class "parent of_leaves">  <!-- Select this one -->
     <li><div class="function leaf">Function number 1.1</div></li>
     <li><div class="function leaf">Function number 1.2</div></li>
     <li><div class="function leaf">Function number 1.3</div></li>
     <li><div class="function leaf">Function number 1.4</div></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><div class="function parent">Parent function 2</div>
   <ul class="parent of_both">
    <li><div class="function leaf">Function number 2.1</div></li>
    <li><div class="function leaf">Function number 2.2</div></li>
    <li><div class="function parent">Function number 2.3</div>
     <ul class="parent of_leaves">  <!-- and this one! -->
      <li><div class="function leaf">Sub function number 2.3.1</div></li>
      <li><div class="function leaf">Sub function number 2.3.2</div></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

**CSS**

The css is now simply:

```
ul.parent.of_leaves { color: red }
```